# Experience Manager: "Update Preview Your changes to this page is not up to date"

Tags: web8, experience-manager, dd4t, session-preview

I'm using SDL Web 8.5 with DD4T 2 (.NET) and Experience Manager in code. I've also got `DDD4T.IsPreview` set to true in the `web.config`:

Page view:

```
@if (XpmExtensions.XpmMarkupService.IsSiteEditEnabled())
{
    @Html.Raw(XpmExtensions.XpmMarkupService.RenderXpmMarkupForPage(Model, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SDL.Instance"]))
}
```

Model:

```
[ContentModel("example", true)]
public class Example : IViewModel
{
    [TextField(FieldName = "example_text")]
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}
```

Component view:

```
<div>
    @if (XpmExtensions.XpmMarkupService.IsSiteEditEnabled())
    {
        @Model.StartXpmEditingZone()
    }
    <p>@Model.XpmEditableField(m => m.Text)</p>
</div>
```

This renders the XPM markup as expected. I can then edit the page as expected. Updating the title, the "Update Preview" shows a yellow icon with a message: "Update Preview Your changes to this page is not up to date. Your changes to this page make an update of the page preview necessary".

What I've tried:

- Verified that Discovery service is setup and up and running
- Verified that Session Content Service is registered to Discovery
- Verified that Session Preview Service is registered to Discovery
- Verified that Session Content and Session Preview's `cd_storage_conf.xml` have been configured to point to the Session Content DB via `SessionWrapper`.
- Verified that the details of the session DB are correct
- Checked the logs for session preview and session content services and found no error
- Checked the CM event logs

Would anyone have any idea of what else I could try?

**Update:**

If I run this locally and click the "Update Preview" I get an error:

> No Publication Target or Target Type is defined for this Experience
>   Manager-enabled Web site. To resolve this problem, Contact your SDL
>   Web administrator.

But clicking the "Update Preview" from the DEV site deployed on another server, then it simply reloads the page as expected without the error.

**Update:**

I removed caching by commenting out `DD4T.CacheSettings.Default` and attempted to update a component through Experience Manager and this time I get "Committing all changes" but it's stuck like this for several minutes until I quit the editing session.

**Update:**

Apologies for my late response:

Rick Pannekoek: GetPreviewToken request is throwing 500 error locally and returns 200 on DEV and TEST, I don't have a cd_ambient_conf.xml in the web app and localhost TTM mapping exists.

Velmurugan: I've verified that Inline Editing Disable Session Preview is selected "No".

Rajesh: I'll get started with setting the log level to Debug to get more information.

Comment: Further things to verify: the browser should do a `GetPreviewToken` request, which returns a Session Token. Then it should do a subsequent request to your Web App with that token in a `preview-session-token` cookie.

Comment: How does your Web App's `cd_ambient_conf.xml` look?

Comment: Regarding the first error you mentioned: do you have a TTM mapping with a `localhost` base URL?

Comment: You could also set the log level to Debug in your Session Preview Service to get more information about the issue.

Comment: To make sure In the CMS settings -> Inline Editing     Disable Session Preview (selected No)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions all; I'll investigate each point and will update this ticket once I have more information.

Comment: Hi Tim. I appreciate that it was a while ago, but did you manage to find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I'm afraid that there's no resolution just yet.

Comment: Hey Tim. Any update on this please? The question is super useful for diagnosing problems btw!